# Odd unselected/light-colored face when UV unwrapping torus?

Tags: uv

Whenever I unwrap a torus in Blender (2.92), I always see a single face that *appears* unselected (i.e. appears plain grey rather than orange tinged) despite its vertices being selected:

[image: unselected face]

I see a similar effect in both the *UV Editor* and the *3D Viewport*.

I don't see this effect when e.g. working with a UV sphere or a cube.

It doesn't seem to affect anything but I'm wondering what Bender is trying to tell me with this light-colored or unselected face?

Comment: That's the active, not unselected. Active is usually the last selected face/edge/vert. Sometimes it's very useful for example if you want to copy modifieres to the selected objects from the active or bake textures from other objects to the active, or merge verts to the last selected's position, or if you want to use UV wrapping by "Follow Active Quads"

Comment: Thanks, now I know its name, it's easy to find [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/active_element.html) in the documentation. According to documentation, I should also see some indicator of the _Active Element_ even if I haven't got all vertices selected (as in the picture) but if I unselect everything this face then looks (to me) no different from the other.

Comment: @GeorgeHawkins that is normal. The active element will in some types remain active even if it is no longer selected: it’s properties are still displayed in the Properties panel, etc.

Comment: @FFeller - if you want to add your comment as an answer the I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the active, not unselected. Active is usually the last selected face/edge/vert. Sometimes it's very useful for example if you want to copy modifieres to the selected objects from the active or bake textures from other objects to the active, or merge verts to the last selected's position, or if you want to use UV wrapping by "Follow Active Quads"

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/active_element.html